# Thrust of accelerating vs stationary water bottle rocket

Tags: fluid-dynamics, flow, rocket-science

When a water bottle rocket accelerates it might leave some water behind, as is (exaggeratedly) shown in Fig 2. The smaller the nozzle the less water is left behind, but let's say the nozzle is rather big for argument's sake.

This left-behind water gives rise to additional mass flow (on top of the mass flow already caused by the pressure difference) as it exits the nozzle, producing thrust and further acceleration. This further acceleration causes an even greater amount of water to be left behind, contributing to higher mass flow more thrust.

**My question is this**: Is the thrust of an accelerating water bottle rocket (Fig 2) higher than the thrust of a stationary one (Fig 1)? Assume zero gravity.

Please correct me if I've misunderstood something.

[image]

Comment: Sorry but I don't quite see how the considerations of the first paragraph relate to the question in the end. You talk about different nozzle sizes but then ask a question about stationary vs moving bottle rockets - which seemingly has nothing to do with nozzle size? But moreover, that first paragraph is quite unclear to me. Eventually all the water leaves, no matter what the nozzle size is - the whole point of the water is to be ejected out the back to give thrust. Is this clear to you? It might help you to discuss "rate of ejection" and "thrust" vs "total ejection" and "total impulse"

Comment: I've seen high frequency load cell readings of thrust vs. time for water bottle rockets.  The data indicate that there is a mixture of air and water exiting the bottle at all times, with the proportion of air/water varying through a wide range over short time intervals.  This means that the thrust is definitely not constant as the bottle rocket accelerates.